# Is it possible to generate a Core Data structure programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am currently working on a project which may require the ability to generate a Core Data model and classes automatically from a JSON feed which describes each object, it's properties and relationships. This would enable our company to quickly generate a working core data database from our CRM at the start of each project.

Is this possible/easy to achieve? If so, does anyone have any tips on where I can get started?
I have already created various iOS apps which use Core Data but I have never made one which needs to automatically create a Core Data model.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a Core Data model dynamically. An `NSManagedObjectModel` can be created without a stored model, and `NSEntityDescription`/`NSAttributeDescription` instances can be defined and added to it before being passed to an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. Apple has an example of doing this in their [Core Data Utility Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/03_createModel.html).